# Location of files after erroneous rename command

Tags: regular-expression, rename

Newbie here... just tried to change a filename that had 2 dots in its name to a single dot using

```
rename 's/.././' filename
```

The file has disappeared but I don't think it has been removed as there is still the same amount of space in memory. Where would this file have been sent to?

Answer (score 20):

The file is called `.lename` now.

(This is assuming the file was called `filename` before, your "real" file will have a different name I guess. But however the file was called, the first two characters have been substituted with a `.`.)

This is because a dot in regular expression is a [special character](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl2/prog/ch05_03.htm) meaning *match any character*. So, `..` is any two characters. As `rename` only replaces the first match unless you added the *global* modifier (`g`), the first two characters of your given filename have been replaced.

Note, that the "replacement" in [`s/regex/replacement/modifiers`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html#Search-and-replace) is not a regular expression, and thus the `.` on the right side of your expression `s/.././` works as you expected.

---

Now, where is your file:

Files beginning with a `.` are hidden files. Thus, you won't see them by running `ls`. Run `ls -a` to reveal those files.

Rename your file back using `mv .lename filename`

---

Next time, escape characters that are special to regular expressions:

```
rename 's/\.\././' filename
```

Also, you could use `rename -n ...` to do a dry-run and check the results before performing the actual renaming. That would have shown you something like this:

```
rename(filename, .lename)
```

Comment: Also, you may have started an XY-problem with the regexp. You can rename a file by using the `mv` command. This command does not have problems with filesnames starting with a dot. Adding two dashes even lets problems with filenames beginning with a dash go away: `mv -- -oldfilename newfilename` (if the file was named `-oldfilename` before). This looks much simpler than a regexp.